# PHP get value from a array by passing value from another array without using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I've two arrays `$products` and `$id_n_qty` $id_n_qty array contains Product id and its quantity where $products array contains all products with their IDs  and name.

```
$products = array(1=>"Shampoo",2=>"Towel");
$id_n_qty = array(1=>3);
```

My question is how can i get the Product name when i have the `$id_n_qty` with me without using `php foreach`?

Thanks

Comment: Is $id_n_qty array always 1 array in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `array_keys` like

```
$key_val = array_keys($id_n_qty);
echo $products[$key_val[0]];
```

Considering that you have only single array in the `$id_n_qty`.

Comment: I think it needs `$id_n_qty` values. Not keys.

Comment: Its keys are `product id` and its value are `quantity`

Comment: its will throw an error **Illegal offset type**  if you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the key for `$id_n_qty` matches the keys in `$products`, you simply need to investigate the key values.

```
$product_names = array_intersect_key($products, $id_n_qty);
```

Note that this gives you the product names for all key values that are in $id_n_qty, thus the $product_names variable is an array.

Comment: @ravisoni I was actually thinking of the array_intersect_key logic backwards.  I have corrected answer, which is actually even simpler than before

Answer (score 0):

If like you said you have single array, you can get the ID like this:

```
// Getting ID
$id = key(reset($id_n_qty));
// Getting Quantity
$qty = $id_n_qty[$id];
```

But I must say this is not an elegant way to do it. You could get the id and quantity as seperate item then it will be more elegant to get it:

```
// First item is ID and second item is Quantity
$id_n_qty = array(1, 3);

// Getting ID and Quantity:
list($id, $quantity) = $id_n_qty;
```

As you see it is easy and looking good. If you can convert the array to this that is.